# Form has no value even if I passed a value in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

So I have this problem where I pass value from typescript to input element. Value is shown in the screen but in the `ngForm` parameters it says value is empty and the form is invalid.

This is the HTML component:

```
<form #editForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(editForm)" novalidate autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" name="sysid" id="sysid" readonly value="{{userList.sysid}}">
    <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter username" name="username" #username="ngModel" ngModel required [class.invalid]="username.invalid" aria-describedby="unameErr" value="{{userList.username}}">
            <small *ngIf="username.invalid" id="unameErr" class="form-text">Username is Required</small>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" placeholder="Enter First Name" name="firstname" #firstname="ngModel" ngModel required [class.invalid]="firstname.invalid" aria-describedby="fnameErr" value="{{userList.firstname}}" oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()">
            <small *ngIf="firstname.invalid" id="fnameErr" class="form-text">First Name is Required</small>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" [disabled]="editForm.invalid">
</form>
```

This is my typescript:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.formId = +params['formId']; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
    });

    this.userList = {
      sysid: "",
      username: "",
      firstname: ""
    }

    this.getUserByIdnew(this.formId);
  }

 getUserByIdnew(formSysid: number) {
    this.apiservice.getUserbyIdnew(formSysid).subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.userList = {
        sysid: data.sysid,
        username: data.username,
        firstname: data.fname
      }
    })
  }

onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    console.log(form);
  }

}
```

And I try to submit and this is shown in the console log:

[image]

As you can see status is "INVALID" and username and firstname has no value even if it is displayed in the screen in this image below:

[image: Image2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use input value attribute along with ngModel. Instead use ngModel directive to bind the value.

```
 <form #editForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(editForm)" novalidate autocomplete="off">
        <input type="text" name="sysid" id="sysid" readonly value="{{userList.sysid}}">
        <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter username" name="username" #username="ngModel" [ngModel]="userList.username" required [class.invalid]="username.invalid" aria-describedby="unameErr" >
                <small *ngIf="username.invalid" id="unameErr" class="form-text">Username is Required</small>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" placeholder="Enter First Name" name="firstname" #firstname="ngModel" [ngModel]="userList.firstname" required [class.invalid]="firstname.invalid" aria-describedby="fnameErr"  oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()">
                <small *ngIf="firstname.invalid" id="fnameErr" class="form-text">First Name is Required</small>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" [disabled]="editForm.invalid">
    </form>
```